# Query performance on record type vs flatten table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with "orders", and "order lines" that come as JSON, and it is simple to store it as JSON in [BigQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery). I can run a process to flatten the file to rows, but it is a burden, and makes the BigQUery table bigger.

What would be a best performance structure for BigQuery? Assuming I have queries on sum or products, and sales in order lines.

And what is the best practice to number of "records" (or "order lines") in a record column? Can it contain thousands or is it aimed for a few? Assuming I would query it like in a [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) document based database.

This will help me plan the right architecture.

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery's columnar architecture is designed to handle nested and repeated fields in a highly performant manner, and in general can return query results as fast as it would if those records were flattened. In fact, in some cases, (depending on your data and the types of queries you are running) using already nested records can actually allow you to avoid subqueries that tack on an extra step.

Short answer: Don't worry about flattening, keep your data in the nested structure, the query performance will generally be the same either way.

However, as to your second question: Your record limit will be determined by how much data you can store in a single record. Currently BigQuery's [per row maximum is 100MB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs). You can have many, many repeated fields in a single record, but they need to fit into this limit.