# How does bigquery handle queries for objects

Tags: google-bigquery

I see there's a couple of docs on the topic, but I'm not sure I completely understand it. The docs from google seems to suggest that keeping [data nested and repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196568/query-performance-on-record-type-vs-flatten-table-in-bigquery.) doesn't impact the performance, however is this comparison to just normalizing or is it overall?

For example, if there's a json object like below:

```
{
     "main_object": {
         "secondary_object": [
          {
             "ternary_object": {
                 "property1": "value"
                 "property2": "value2"
             }
          }]
    }
}
```

Is it better to move ternary_object into main_object? Also, if I want to query by property1, is it better to have it as part of the main object?

[Query performance on record type vs flatten table in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196568/query-performance-on-record-type-vs-flatten-table-in-bigquery)